# Best approach for android autocomplete search box

Tags: android, file-io, autocomplete, search-engine

I would like any suggestions on how to implement a fast autocomplete search box on android.

Useful info:

1) Data will be stored locally on phone memory. No database or network should be needed.

2) There is no restriction on the type of file that will be used. Could be simple text file, XML file, or whatever suits best.

3) The file will contain a large amount of records that are distinguished by a unique ID/CODE.
There will be also a human readable name for the record and a text with more info on the record like

```
CODE:       HUMAN_REPRESENTATION:       EXTRA_INFO:
AF32        Orange                      The orange (specifically, the sweet orange) is the fruit of the citrus species Citrus...
AF33        Apple                       The apple is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree...
```

4) The user will type on the text area the HUMAN_REPRESENTATION string he wants, and he will be shown a list of matching records to select of.

5) While typing he should be given auto-complete suggestions so he would not have to type the exact phrase.

6) The amount of records will be about 15,000.

So which is the best way to store and retrieve data as fast as possible?
What file type would you suggest? Should the data be split into many files? Can I use a specific API?

I would really be thankful for any directions here, as I am new in android development, but experienced in desktop applications.

---

**EDIT :**

Since I had no answers in many days, I would like to know if my question is not clear enough or if it has already been answered. Please comment.